# Cannot navigate to conditionally set Screen with react native navigation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am fairly new to react native and it could be that I have set up my code poorly, however, I have my Navigator conditionally set - based on if the user is logged in or not.

```js
const App: React.FunctionComponent<{}> = () => {
  const auth = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth.value);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {auth == null ? (
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          <Stack.Screen name="Sign In" component={LoginScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      ) : (
        <Drawer.Navigator
          initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
          drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
          drawerContentOptions={{
            activeTintColor: color.primaryDark,
            itemStyle: {
              backgroundColor: 'transperant',
              borderColor: color.primaryDark,
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
              opacity: 0.8,
            },
          }}
          drawerStyle={styles.drawer}>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

As seen in the code above, the navigation will be set based on if `auth` is set, which is the auth token of the user. This works great and the problem that I am having is when logging out.

The log out button is in the Drawer:

```js
function CustomDrawerContent(props: DrawerContentComponentProps) {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const onLogOutPress = () => {
    dispatch(logOut());
    props.navigation.navigate('Sign In');
  };
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView
      {...props}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.drawerContentContainer}>
      <View style={styles.drawerUpperItemsAlignment}>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      </View>
      <DrawerItem
        label="Logout"
        onPress={onLogOutPress}
        style={styles.drawerBottomItems}
      />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}
```

Where the redux `logOut` action only resets the token state. When clicking on the log out button, I get the error

> ERROR    The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Sign In"} was not handled by any navigator.
>
> Do you have a screen named 'Sign In'?

I assume this happens because of conditionally rendering the navigation (based on `auth`). But if that is the case, how can I have the "Sign In" screen available in the navigation of the drawer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dispatch will is async and will take time to change your redux.

When you navigate, the redux didn't take effect yet so your 'Sign In' screen doesn't exist.

You don't need to navigate because when redux take effect, your app will navigate automatically to 'Sign in' because it is the default screen of your Navigator when auth == null.

Comment: I lost about an hour trying out different ways to navigate to the screen and it turned out redux and react-native are so awesome, they will do it for me.